# chrome is fine with jsfiddle but firefox isn't

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, jsfiddle

**SAME URL FOR PROVIDED**

[Firfox](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/Xj9m8/) :

[Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/Xj9m8/) :

jscode is bellow

```
function css(a){
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
    for(var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for(var r in rules) {
            if(a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}

function css2json(css){
        var s = {};
        if(!css) return s;
        if(css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
            for(var i in css) {
                if((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                    s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
                }
            }
        } else if(typeof css == "string") {
            css = css.split("; ");          
            for (var i in css) {
                var l = css[i].split(": ");
                s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
            };
        }
        return s;
    }

var style = css($("#elementToGetAllCSS"));
$("#elementToPutStyleInto").css(style);
```

There is a js error within line 25 to 28 in firefox but chrome isn't.I can't get an idea for this.what is the problem ? am i drunk ?

Comment: Are you drunk *enough*?

Comment: You might be drunk.  You included the same link to jsfiddle twice and called one chrome and the other firefox.

Comment: yeah.See it from chrome and firefox.firfox reported a js error in line 25 to 28 but chrome is not

Comment: @JamesMontagne didn't u see?

Comment: I don't see any error. Have you tried disabling plugins?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 did u see 2 black divs in the jsfiddle result section throuh firefox ?

Comment: No I do not. But I also don't get an error

Comment: Can't answer your question. But if you are looking for [this...](http://jsfiddle.net/Xj9m8/2/) It's Simpler and works anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You have a `/` at the start of your `<br/>` which might be affecting it?

Try this one without it http://jsfiddle.net/Xj9m8/1/

Comment: I'm saying a js error.There isn't problem with chrome but firefox there is an error

Comment: I get no errors in either Firefox or Chrome, they just don't look the same.